# NBA Continuation Rule

Tags: rules, basketball, nba

If a player is fouled on a drive to the basket and continuation is granted but then commits a charging foul while continuing his drive, what is the call?

Answer (score 1):

Not just during the drive to the basket, but any foul committed in the act of shooting can result in the offensive player getting one free throw (If the shot is made), or two (If the shot is not made).

Any foul made after the whistle is called, is not considered. Unless it's a dead ball foul, in which case technical fouls are given to the players.
You can read more about Dead Ball fouls [here](https://videorulebook.nba.com/archive/technical-foul-dead-ball-contact-345/)